# Webserver concurrent connections

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, connections

Where can I get statistics of concurrent connections that can be handled by Apache and IIS? Which one will serve more requests in peak times?

Thank you, Sri

Comment: Sorry, voting to close this one. Without any constraints given (web app architecture, programming language used, HTTP semantics, etc) any answer to this will be speculation.

Answer (score 0):

That's hard to answer.  As always, the answer to questions like this is "it depends." What type of requests? Static? Dynamic? Large? Small? Internal? External? A bit more information about your environment is needed to answer with any degree of accuracy.